# How to make sure to have all used symbols in "List of symbols"?

Tags: symbols, glossaries

For my thesis I wanted to include a list of symbols, to generate an easy reference for the reader. Unfortunately, this thought came quite late, and I already have written more than ~200 pages, with a rather large number of different symbols.

Is there a way to make sure that I did not forget a symbol when creating the list of symbols? Of course, one option would be to use something like

```
\newglossaryentry{symb:Phi}{
name=$\varphi$,
description={An angle.},
sort=symbolphi, type=symbolslist
}
```

in the entry list, and

```
$\gls{symb:Phi}$
```

in the text itself, but that would make almost all equations extremely unreadable and unwielding in code.

Are there other options?

Comment: For all symbols that are created with a single macro (like `\varphi`) you can extract all macro names from the document with a simple regex (`\\\w+`), sort them and remove duplicates, then manually remove macros that are not a symbol (like `\section`) of which there should not be a large amount, what remains are all your symbols that you can check against your glossary.

Comment: How would I look for symbols created with simple letters? But the approach looks good!

Comment: @arc_lupus If the "simple letter" symbols are produced by non-ascii characters in the source, you could get a list of them with a regex as well, e.g., with GNU grep: `grep -P -o '[^[:ascii:]]' filename.tex | sort | uniq`.

Comment: Or any simple letter in isolation (`[^\w]\w[^\w]`), maybe also filter out dots to prevent hits on abbreviations (`[^\w\.]\w[^\w\.]`). Of course this quickly becomes error-prone but with some luck you will catch a number of symbols that you have missed before.